# About a ℙ≠ℕℙ proof

Tags: np-complete, complexity-classes

**Executable:** Sat *prog* 
**Definition:** The exit status of "Sat *prog*" is 1 iff there exists an instance 
*prog arg* which runs in P-time and the exit status is 1. 

From the definition, Sat computes a ℕℙ problem. 
If ℕℙ=ℙ, then, an executable f exists that "Sat f" should run in P-time: 

// C source of executable f 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(int, char* []) { 
return system("Sat f")? 0:1; 
} 

**Brief analysis:** 
If Sat(f)==1, from definition of f, f(*)==0. But, from definition of Sat, ∃x,f(x)==1 ... Contradiction 
If Sat(f)==0, from definition of f, f(*)==1. But, from definition of Sat, ∀x,f(x)==0 ... Contradiction (Exact negation should read: For all *prog arg* instance, *prog arg* does not run in P-time or the exit status of *prog arg* is not 1). 

**Conclusion:** If ℙ=ℕℙ, there exists instances like f that Sat cannot decide.
Therefore, ℙ≠ℕℙ.

----------------------
**Answer to possible questions:**

1. Given a polynomial formula P(x). We measure the execution steps t of an
   executable f (or function f(x)). If t<=P(|f|+|x|), we say f(x) runs in P-times.
   Note that the definition of Sat (and ℕℙ) does not require *prog* be a "P-time
   executable". *prog* can actually never terminate. In this case, the exit staus
   of "Sat *prog*" is 0.
2. Sat is not shown undecidable, because the provided example f is only valid
   when "Sat *prog*" is assumed to compute in P-time.

I am not familiar with complexity theory. Such proof does not look
like a traditional theoretical proof 
 (would be many pages). Nonetheless, it is thought a valid proof, because the argument is supported by 'real programs', what can go wrong?

Comment: You are claiming to have a solution for a well-known, difficult open problem. This is [an extraordinary claim requiring extraordinary evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcello_Truzzi#.22Extraordinary_claims.22). You have not provided such so there is not much to talk about. Even if you had, this would not be a good post for SE; it is not our goal here to make broad advances to science in a single post. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/how-to-deal-with-questions-about-crank-heavy-topics) for a related discussion.

Comment: What does "Sat *prog*" mean?  What does it mean to say that "instance *prog arg* runs in P-time"?  Why do you think "Sat f" runs in P-time?  What does it mean for Sat to decide an instance?

Comment: A clarifying section "Answer to possible question" is added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you showed is that no such program "Sat" can exist. Note that the complexity didn't matter here, since the argument still holds valid for any other complexity classes (a sign of this is that the analysis does not make a reference to the complexity of "Sat").

In fact, this is a well known fact! One can reduce the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to the description of the problem that your "Sat" claims to solve, and since there is no turing machine (i.e, program) that solves the halting problem (and also always halts) - there also won't be one for this.

Comment: Thank, I take your answer. I think the error can be fixed easily. The system says I need to wait for 7 days to post another question.

Comment: @wij, you should probably look very carefully at how you formulate your statement, how you define everything - and try to be as pedantic as possible. Most likely, this statement cannot be "fixed" (at least to my knowledge in complexity theory) - so try to be as skeptical as possible with *every* step of your proof. You might notice a "gap" in one of those steps - which will render the proof invalid.

Comment: The point is that the $\mathbb{P}$ vs $\mathbb{NP}$ problem is well-studied, so attempts from people who lack a formal knowledge of complexity theory tend to sound "believable" at first, but really aren't correct when you notice the full picture with all of the details. So beware of your own attempts! But its still good to try to prove/disprove - it improves your understanding in the area  :)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confused about what it means for a program to run in polynomial time. It expresses a relationship between the size of the input offered to the program and its execution time on that input, namely, that that time is bounded by a polynomial in the input size.

> The exit status of "Sat prog" is 1 iff there exists an instance *prog arg* which runs in P-time and the exit status is 1.

It does not make any sense to say that *prog arg* "runs in P-time". The time it takes *prog* to run on *arg* is just a number, it is not a function. What you need to look at is the relationship between the time it takes *prog* to run on any possible *arg* and the size of those *arg*s.

> From the definition, *Sat* computes a ℕℙ problem.

It doesn't. *Sat* computes an uncomputable problem, which is why it can't exist (see nir sharar's answer). Your definition of *Sat* has nothing to do with ℕℙ or with satisfiability of Boolean formulas. What relationship do you see?